# Purpose of "match_parent" in android:layout_width/height for top view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

A noobish question.

I am curious as to the purpose of having "match_parent" in the two xml attributes for the top level layout view like LinearLayout.
I believe "match_parent" indicates that the view wants to be as big as its parent.
But in the case of top level layout view (LinearLayout) there is no parent..?

Comment: These views have window as there parent. They definitely make sense for surfaceviews when using them. Same layout file can be inflated or set as parent view. that's y the attribute is required Theres is no need to spend too much time thinking about this

Comment: Agree with the above comment by Pulkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view u see on the screen is actually attached to`Window` the upper layout property "match_parent" is for `Window`.

see [window class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html)

and [window manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

"match_parent" means it adjust view in total amount of screen.

In context of parent or chiled.

There is a no difference between in parent level or chiled level.